# Why can I export with or without writing export in a `Ambient Namespaces`?

Tags: typescript

[The document of ts ambient-namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#ambient-namespaces)

Why can I export with or without writing export in a `Ambient Namespaces`?

And what is the difference between Ambient Namespaces (with declare) and ordinary namespaces (without declare) in typescript?

```
declare namespace Test {
  export interface A {}
  interface B {}
  export type C = {}
  type D = {}
  export const a = 1
  const b = 2
}

type Test1 = Test.D // this is effective，but type D is not exported.
```